# Autoclick in PHP/HTML

Tags: javascript

There is a link which when clicked, sends the email. Below is the code:

```
$message->postInfoMessage('<a href="#" onclick="emailTranscript(); return false;">'.JText::_('COM_AWDLIVESUPPORT_LANG50').'</a>', $chat);
```

I wanted this to be automatically clicked and executed whenever this function is called. By this it would not be click dependent and it will automatically send the email.

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi solved my requirement by calling the function as:

```
$this->emailTranscript();
```

Thanks all who tried suggesting. :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    emailTranscript();
</script>
```

Just make sure it is executed after the `emailTranscript()` function is initialized.

Because basically the snippet you post creates a link, when clicked upon `emailTranscript()` is executed. With the line above it is just executed, without any condition.

Answer (score 0):

Just use onload event instead of onclick event   that's it.

Comment: This could be acomment

Comment: Then just execute javascript remove hyperlink

Comment: When you want hyperlink to be automatically clicked then there is no use to give users to link to click it remove hyperlink and just execute your code

Answer (score 0):

Simply add these lines

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
             emailTranscript();
        };
</script>
```